# LED won't turn on and serial monitor won't display values

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to use my Arduino to record some values from a photo-resister. The idea is when a character other than g is read the LED will turn on and 512 values will be recorded.

When I type in a character in the serial monitor whether it is g or not it just says 1 or 0 but doesn't not provide me with the values I need from the photo-resistor. My code is as follows:

```
int timeOut = 60000;
int pollTime = 0;
int time = 0;
unsigned long startTime = 0;
unsigned long endTime = 0;
int x = 0;
int Vs[512];
int analogPin = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  while (!waitFor('g', 200, 60e6)) {}
  analogWrite(9, 128);
  startTime = micros();
  for (x = 0; x < 512; x = x + 1)  {
    Vs[x] = (analogRead(analogPin));
  }
  endTime = micros();
  for (int x = 0; x < 512; x = x + 1)  {
    Serial.println(Vs[x]);
  }
  Serial.println(endTime - startTime);
}

void loop() {
}

boolean waitFor(char in, int pollTime, int timeOut)  {
  boolean done = false;
  char charWait;
  time = micros();
  while (time < timeOut)  {
    if (Serial.available())  {
      charWait = Serial.read();
      done = (charWait == in);
      Serial.println(done);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you never update `time`, then `while (time < timeOut) {...}` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Edgar says, what you need to do is this:

```
bool waitFor(char in, int pollTime, unsigned long timeOut)  
{
  while (micros() < timeOut)  
  {
    if (Serial.available())  
    {
      if (Serial.read() == in)
      {
        Serial.println("done");
        return true;
      }
    }
    delay(pollTime);
  }
  return false;
}
```

If it still doesn't run after that then change setup() to this:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initialising...");
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  while (!waitFor('g', 200, 60e6)) {}
  Serial.println("g command received...");
  analogWrite(9, 128);
  Serial.println("About to start...");
  startTime = micros();
  for (x = 0; x < 512; x = x + 1)  {
    Vs[x] = (analogRead(analogPin));
  }
  endTime = micros();
  Serial.println("Finished...");
  for (int x = 0; x < 512; x = x + 1)  {
    Serial.println(Vs[x]);
  }
  Serial.print("The result is : ");
  Serial.println(endTime - startTime);
  Serial.println("All finished.");
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't print anything to the serial monitor.

Comment: OK.  Can you alter the setup function as above and report what the last line of output is.  If you get no output at all then check you have the correct serial port.

Comment: In the prototype of `waitFor()`, `timeout` should be `unsigned long`: and `int` can be no bigger than 32767.